Splunk query help - startswith endswith
I’m new to Splunk and data querying in general- trying to parse some syslogs and stuck on setting up the query I need.
I’m trying to tally a list of connection drops and calculate duration of sessions being down. The only unique identifiers are in the source_ip (or _raw) fields.
The source_ip fields look like this-
“Neighbor 5.5.5.5 (Tunnel01) is down” and “Neighbor 5.5.5.5 (Tunnel01) is up”.
The IP will vary depending on the session- and I need it match logs where the ip is the same.
What I have so far is-
index=* “(Tunnel01) is down” OR “(Tunnel01) is up” host=* | transaction host startswith=“(Tunnel01) is down” endswith=“(Tunnel01) is up”
This almost works- but what I’ve found is sometime the ips don’t match in the results- completely messing up the data. I need a way to make it so that the IP in log message matched in the startswith matches the IP in the endswith. Something like -
index=* “Tunnel01 is down” OR “(Tunnel01 is up” host=* | transaction host startswith=“(Tunnel01) is down” endswith=“(Tunnel01) is up”
WHERE source_ip in startswith = source_ip in endswith
Any idea how I can make this work? Should I be using a different query altogether? Thanks all for any support.

Use rex to define IP variable and then add it to transaction.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/9.1.2312/SearchReference/Transaction#6._Transactions_with_the_same_session_ID_and_IP_address

Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. None of the tag information should be in the title at all, and neither should the word help. Those details are already known. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know exactly what it is about. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask]. Also, it would help if you at least make an effort to properly comment the code in your question. Help in doing so can be found by clicking the help button ? on the toolbar.

The transaction command can be quite slow.  This method may be faster.  It uses the streamstats command to calculate the difference in timestamps between the 'down' and 'up' events.
index=foo (“Tunnel01 is down” OR “(Tunnel01 is up")
| rex "\s(?<address>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s"
| streamstats window=2 diff(_time) as DowntimeInSecs by address


| rex field=duration "^(?:[^,\n]*,){9}\"\w+\":\"(?P<duration>\d+)\""
| eval durationSec = duration/1000
| table jobName, durationSec, status, count, tps
| eval successStatus=if(status="SUCCESS", "SUCCESS", "FAIL")
| search jobName=BillingMCBSParentJob
| stats count as Count, avg(eval(if(successStatus="SUCCESS",durationSec,null()))) as avgSuccessDuration, avg(eval(if(successStatus="FAIL",durationSec,null()))) as avgFailDuration by successStatus


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
